# Does changing query string in Destination URL via Adwords API trigger editorial?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

This is an ongoing debate at my company. We run massive Adwords accounts. I need to automate  adding or changing query string parameters on large numbers of keywords. Our SEM team is nervous that this could cause the Adwords editorial staff to disable large numbers of keywords while they review the changes (effectively killing traffic).

I can understand why changing the domain or page in the URL might cause this. But changing the query string should not, I would think.

Can anybody confirm/deny this possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2013-03-19**

I'm not sure this qualifies as an "answer". I posted this same question on Google Groups and, as usual, Google was noncommittal. However, this is what I have gathered so far (I'm sharing for posterity):

First of all, "editorial" doesn't seem to be a term that is widely accepted at Google. I'm saying this based on our discussions with our account reps. The term didn't mean much to them and required clarification. So, to clarify, when I say "editorial" I mean Google's process of reviewing your keyword term, ad copy, landing page, and potentially resetting statistics (quality score). This is mostly automated in their system from what I can tell. However, there are times when it appears that human beings actually get involved in the process.

And now the answer: It seems that modifying keyword destination URLs does not cause manual review nor reset of statistics. Possible exceptions are trademarked terms or pharmaceutical terms. I translate that more broadly as "any terms that have special rules".

NOTE: Folks in the Google Groups seem to all agree that modifying URLs at the Creative level DOES reset statistics. So tread carefully.

Here is the Google Group thread.

**UPDATE 2013-07-11**

I'm just talking to myself now. I feel so alone.
I just received the "tumbleweed" award for this post.

The Adwords team finally told us that modifying Destination URLS *should not* affect traffic.

So, we modified several hundred thousand Destination URLs and our SEM Team reported that some of their high volume keywords stopped getting traffic for about 10 days and then magically came back. No explanation. The Adwords team dug up some "expert" from the bowels of their staff and subsequently told us that modifying Destination URLs *does* affect traffic.

However, we were also transitioning these accounts to Enhanced Campaigns at the same time. So the results are inconclusive in my mind.
I don't think even the Adwords team knows how Adwords works.

It's cold here. Need to make a fire...

Comment: I just marked my own answer as the answer. 
Nobody will care.
ROFL